# Is it safe to disable JQMIGRATE?

Tags: magento2, jquery, console, jqmigrate

Seems like it is complaining about using a deprecated pseudo-event. Also, If I remember correctly `console.trace` is used for debugging and should not be shown/needed on live site. The JQMIGATE code seems to do this console.trace which adds notifications in the console.

However, It basically restores deprecated features and behaviors so that older code will still run properly on the current jQuery version and later.

In this case, is it safe to disable it?

Could anyone please guide me with this?